# FirebaseAuthSettings in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase-authentication

Is testing phone auth in an emulator not available in flutter?  I can't seem to find a way to do the below code in flutter.  Is there a package that I need to find or is it not implemented?

```
Android

FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseAuthSettings firebaseAuthSettings = firebaseAuth.getFirebaseAuthSettings();

// Configure faking the auto-retrieval with the whitelisted numbers.
firebaseAuthSettings.setAutoRetrievedSmsCodeForPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, smsCode);
```

Added the code that I am using.  I am calling instantiate().  If I am missing something please let me know.  I am not getting an error, the function is just calling the timeout method.  (PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout)

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

enum PhoneAuthState { Started, CodeSent, CodeResent, Verified, Failed, Error, AutoRetrievalTimeOut }

class FirebasePhoneAuth {
  static var firebaseAuth;
  static var _authCredential, actualCode, phone, status;
  static StreamController<String> statusStream = StreamController();
  static StreamController<PhoneAuthState> phoneAuthState = StreamController(sync: true);
  //static Stream stateStream = phoneAuthState.stream;

  static FirebaseAuth dd = FirebaseAuth.instance;  // .setAutoRetrievedSmsCodeForPhoneNumber("+17015557665", "123456");

  static instantiate({String phoneNumber}) async {
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    phone = phoneNumber;
    startAuth();
  }

  static startAuth() {
    if (!statusStream.hasListener) {
      statusStream.stream
          .listen((String status) => debugPrint("PhoneAuth: " + status));
    } 

    firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phone,
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 10),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
  }

  static final PhoneCodeSent codeSent =
      (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
    actualCode = verificationId;
    addStatus("\nEnter the code sent to " + phone);
    addState(PhoneAuthState.CodeSent);
  };

  static final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
      (String verificationId) {
    actualCode = verificationId;
    addStatus("\nAuto retrieval time out");
    addState(PhoneAuthState.AutoRetrievalTimeOut);
  };

  static final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
      (AuthException authException) {
    addStatus('${authException.message}');
    addState(PhoneAuthState.Error);
    if (authException.message.contains('not authorized'))
      addStatus('App not authroized');
    else if (authException.message.contains('Network'))
      addStatus('Please check your internet connection and try again');
    else
      addStatus('Something has gone wrong, please try later ' +
          authException.message);
  };

  static final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
      (AuthCredential auth) {
    addStatus('Auto retrieving verification code');

    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(auth).then((AuthResult value) {
      if (value.user != null) {
        addStatus(status = 'Authentication successful');
        addState(PhoneAuthState.Verified);
        onAuthenticationSuccessful();
      } else {
        addState(PhoneAuthState.Failed);
        addStatus('Invalid code/invalid authentication');
      }
    }).catchError((error) {
      addState(PhoneAuthState.Error);
      addStatus('Something has gone wrong, please try later $error');
    });
  };

  static void signInWithPhoneNumber(String smsCode) async {
    _authCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: actualCode, smsCode: smsCode);

    firebaseAuth
        .signInWithCredential(_authCredential)
        .then((FirebaseUser user) async {
      addStatus('Authentication successful');
      addState(PhoneAuthState.Verified);
      onAuthenticationSuccessful();
    }).catchError((error) {
      addState(PhoneAuthState.Error);
      addStatus('Something has gone wrong, please try later(signInWithPhoneNumber) $error');
    });
  }

  static onAuthenticationSuccessful() {}

  static addState(PhoneAuthState state){
    phoneAuthState.sink.add(state);
  }

  static void addStatus(String s) {
    statusStream.sink.add(s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by erasing the data on the android emulator, restarting and reinstalling.  I assume there was a caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes my friend you can use number to test on emulater but after added it to your firebase project, with dart flutter after add FirebaseAuth Plugin to your project from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth#-installing-tab-)  in your  pubspec.yaml file

```
 dependencies: 
 firebase_auth: ^0.15.2
```

after add FirebaseAuth you must also integration it to ios and android (or one of them depend on what you need ) from [here](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth#import-the-firebase_auth-plugin)

after do steps Go to your project in firebase then **Authentication** then 
**Sign-in method** and make sure **phone** is enable and add Your Phone Number Wont to **test** like image

[image]

Note :maybe first time every launch app  in emulator you will show code send is time out  so just click you action that make code send to your phone ,and then back and try again without close app ,i hope you understand me

Comment: I have done all of that, but I am still getting a timeout error.

Comment: added my code. 

Here is all I am getting back:
I/flutter (10675): PhoneAuth: 
I/flutter (10675): Auto retrieval time out

Comment: i faced same problem but it happen just first time every launch app so just click you action that make code send code to enter phone ,and then back and try again without close app ,i hope you understand me

Comment: I think I got that.  No change though.  still getting the timeout.